# Why does $entry['slug'] and $entry->slug return different values?

Tags: plugins, craft2

I'm writing a simple plugin for 'Craft 2' and It seems that a `slug` of an entry is returned if you reffer it like: `$entry['slug']` but calling `$entry->slug` returns same value as entry title.

Is there an explanation of why it happens and what is the best practice of getting values of the entry fields with a homemade plugin?

Thanks!

God bless ya'll.

Comment: Usually `$entry->slug` is the correct way. `$entry['slug']` will trigger the `Arrayable` trait and tries to cast your object into an array. Do you do something with your entry or do you change certain values? Is it right after you create a new entry or do you fetch it from your DB? Best practice is to use the object syntax -> `$entry->slug`

Comment: The idea is more like; build a JSON and then send it to another endpoint (call it REST API). And I wanna specify fields which I'm interested in, so they should be customizable. For this kind of scenario do you have a 100% working approach?

Comment: Yes I do. But you didn't answer my questions at all. It doesn't matter what you want to do with the data, all that matters is what you did before you call `$entry['slug']`

Comment: Right. So entries are created some time ago, and yes I fetch em from DB based on some criteria, nothing fancy.

Comment: Could you please insert your code, maybe we get an insight was might be wrong.

Comment: $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);


$criteria->id = $ids;

$criteria->limit = null;

$criteria->with = array('someCoolFieldName');

$entries = $criteria->find();

Comment: Basically Im getting an array of entries and traverse them, in order to fetch all neccesary fields.

Comment: Under the hood Craft does many things automatically and converts many things automatically for you. `$entry->slug` should work for sure.. that's why I asked for your complete code.

Comment: Yes thanks for help!